# How to make a JS object *become* a TypeScript class instance

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have the following class:

```
export class MyClass {
    str: string = '';

    foo() {
        console.log(this.str);
    }
}
```

Then, in some other code:

```
var myObj = {
    str: 'Hello World';
}
```

**How can I convert `myObj` into a `MyClass` instance, so the following line works:**

```
myObj.foo();
// writes 'Hello World' to the console
```

(Please note that I cannot change the creation of `myObj`, because it's created in another library)

## ***** EDIT: *****

I'm still looking for a solution for this. The main problem is that `MyClass` has references to other classes, which maybe have references to `MyClass`. It's a whole object graph that I'm trying to convert to TypeScript classes.

Of every class and every property I know its type, and it matches perfectly with the classes and properties defined on `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:(I've added the MyClass as JS code).

```
function becomeMyClass(o){
  var fn1=function(){
    var thing;
    MyClass.apply(arguments);
    //note: shallow copy only
    for(thing in o){
      if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty
        .call(o,thing)){
          this[thing]=o[thing];
      }
    }
  };
  fn1.prototype=Object.create(MyClass.prototype);
  return new fn1([].slice.call(arguments,1));
}
function MyClass(){
  this.str = "from myclass";
}
MyClass.prototype.foo=function(){
  console.log(this.str);
};
var myObj = {
  str:"from myObj"
}

myC = becomeMyClass(myObj);
console.log(myC.foo());//from myObj
console.log(myC instanceof MyClass);//true
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution, the most readable solution and the one with the fewest lines of code would be to just map it:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.str = myObj.str;

myClass.foo();
```

If the `str` property is mandatory, you could make it a constructor parameter and reduce this by one line...

```
var myClass = new MyClass(myObj.str);

myClass.foo();
```

## Update

If you have many classes in your program with the same properties, perhaps you could encapsulate those properties within a class. For example, if all the classes had properties `name, nickname, avatar` you might wrap them into a `Profile` class. This gives you one property to map should you need to take the profile from one class and add it to another.

However, you know your use case best, so you might be interested in this J[avaScript port of auto-mapper](http://johnkalberer.com/2011/08/24/automapper-in-javascript/), which should easily map your stuff if the properties all have the same names:

Comment: I'm looking for a generic way that doesn't create a new object. I have many references to the objects I want to convert, and they are much more complex than just with one property `str`.

Comment: Do the property names always match?

Comment: Yes, the property names do always match.

Answer (score 1):

Is this other library that creates the object always going to return that object from the function? You could create a .d.ts definitions file that defines that the specific function returns MyClass.

Comment: But in this case the `MyClass` constructor won't be executed, will it? So there's the same problem as in using `__proto__`.

Answer (score 0):

Found it out, now I'm using the following utility method:

```
export class Util {
    static become(obj: any, newClass: any) {
        obj.__proto__ = (<any>(new newClass())).__proto__;
    }
}
```

The following call converts `myObj` into a `MyClass` instance by assigning the right prototype:

```
Util.become(myObj, MyClass);
```

Maybe there's another, more elegant way that doesn't involve the use of `__proto__`.

Comment: If there happened to be code in the constructor for the other class, it won't have fired, making this solution not necessarily portable in all cases. You might want to consider just copying the data into a new instance. That way constructors and property setters have a chance to execute.

Comment: You should not fiddle with ```__proto__```. It is non-standard in ES5 and below, and even in ES6 it is discouraged to set it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you have a lot of objects with an unknown list of properties, I take it you can't write a constructor for MyClass to take in an arbitrary object and create a MyClass instance from its properties. Therefore you can't meaningfully "convert" myObj to an instance of MyClass.

Fiddling with myObj's prototype is not a very nice thing to do. See the warning at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

That leaves you with using duck typing: `MyClass.foo.call(myObj);` This will only work if MyClass's methods only refer to properties available on myObj, i.e., you don't expect the constructor of MyClass to have set any other properties to default values, etc. (since in this case the MyClass constructor has effectively never run).