# What is the most efficient way to assign __proto__?

Tags: typescript, prototype

I need to assign the `__proto__` ([as found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302812/assign-proto-to-an-interface-to-turn-it-into-an-object-clever-or-dangerous)) to an object that is passed through a web worker postMessage().  I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455702/how-to-make-a-js-object-become-a-typescript-class-instance/21455862#21455862) but it creates a class on each call and that strikes me as inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

ps - This should be very safe because it's reattaching the methods to an object that had that exact `__proto__` before it was dropped in the serialization.

Comment: Beware of "inefficient" before you've got the measurements :)

Comment: "I need to assign `__proto__`" - before hacking away, are you sure you do? It almost always is a design smell.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg I agree with your general comment. Our specific case is we're passing a very large object (basically objects with lists and those lists have lists of objects) and the web worker serialization is basically serialize the data and drop the __proto__. Setting the __proto__ restores the passed data to being a class. I think that's solid. And it avoids a ton of memory allocations and the overhead not just of recreating every object, but making the garbage collector spend a lot more time.

Comment: @SteveFenton I agree, that's why I'm asking. I'm hoping someone here has timed each approach and can answer which is best.

Comment: You want to compare `x.__proto__ = y;` versus *what*, exactly?

Comment: @DavidThielen benchmark tests are meaningless - you have to measure your program, not one line of code that will be used in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found this solution but it creates a class on each call and that strikes me as inefficient

This call `new newClass()` is not inefficient in the general sense. It is only as inefficient as calling `new Class` on its own just a few more things, i.e. creating a new obj for use in `this` (as simple as `{}`) and settings `newClass.prototype` to be `__proto__` in the returned object.

> Is there a more efficient way to do this

Compared to  `obj.__proto__ = (<any>(new newClass())).__proto__;` ... yes very much so, Just do :

`obj.__proto__ = newClass.prototype`

Note that this takes away the opportunity from `newClass` to setup any members on `this` i.e. class members. But if you already have them on `obj` then you don't need to go through running the constructor overhead.

Comment: It didn't work. I have the code "(<any>body).__proto__ = ListBody.prototype;" and after that line I tried calling "body.isEmpty()" which is a method in ListBody. It told me that was undefined.

Also, in IE 10 before that line the object had no __proto__ member, just prototype. This is data received in a web worker postMessage() call.

Any ideas? thanks - dave

Comment: And now I have it working. But I don't know what made the difference between working and not working...